# Python Beautifulsoup searching Google

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm fairly new to Python, so the the IDE's error isn't making much sense.

I have two text files:

```
text2.txt  <------- contains list of company names
text1.txt  <------- after executing the program, this should be filled with url
```

The aim of this script below is to take as input a list of names from text2.txt, and Google the name of the company along with word "press release".

The python script should then only write 1 url to text1.txt for each company name, and that url should contain in it the word "press" or "release".

The goal of this script is to find a press release url for each company name.

I am getting invalid syntax for using "||" and even if I remove the if statement, the url from Google isn't being found or written in array. Can someone suggest what I am doing wrong? Here is the code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


lines = open("test2.txt").read().splitlines()
links = []

for line in lines:
    r = requests.get('https://www.google.com/search?q={}&gbv=1&sei=YwHNVpHLOYiWmQHk3K24Cw'.format((line + " press release").replace(" ", "+")))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
    for item in soup.find_all('h3', attrs={'class': 'r'}):
        i = (item.a['href'][7:]).find("release")
        b = (item.a['href'][7:]).find("press")
        if (i != -1 || b != -1):
            links.append(item)
            break;

f = open("test.txt","w")

for item in links:
  f.write("%s\n" % item)

f.close()
```

Comment: `||` is not valid Python syntax. Use `or` instead.

Comment: @JF that works! Thank you! no longer getting that error, but for some reason the google search isn't outputting anything. I've tried by hard coding a value to search rather than getting input from text file, and that works, but getting input from file to search doesn't work. Could it be because of the \n that is in a textfile?

Comment: You have removed the newlines when you split, you need to add some sample input. Also not sure why you are using find

Comment: @PadraicCunningham good point. One thing I found out is if I do too many queries in one moment, Google asks for Captcha, but not sure if that is causing the no url in this case.

Comment: yep, google does not like being scraped. You could try adding  user-agent but it is google so..

Comment: I would try using bing instead its ok with being scraped.

Comment: I'll try rewriting my code a different way, and if it works then I'll post the solution here...if it doesn't work then it's Google that's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use google module in python for google search

```
from google import search
for url in search(query, stop=10):
     print url
```

Answer (score 0):

More easier and modern approach of reading and writing files using context manager:

```py
with open("company_names.txt", mode="r") as in_file, \
     open("saved_company_names.txt", mode="w") as out_file:
         # something

# VS

with open("saved_company_names.txt", mode="w") as out_file:
     with open("company_names.txt", mode="r") as in_file:
          # something
```

---

You don't have to do URL slicing since you can check the word in the entire URL:

```py
 # Example for "Tesla Press Release"
 if "press" or "press-releases" in soup.select_one(".yuRUbf a")["href"]:
     # -> https://ir.tesla.com/press
```

---

Make sure you're using [`user-agent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/User_agent) as default `requests` `user-agent` is [`python-requests`](https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/589c4547338b592b1fb77c65663d8aa6fbb7e38b/requests/utils.py#L808-L814) and websites understand it and might block your request. [Check what's your `user-agent`](https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-is-my-user-agent) and add to [request headers](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#custom-headers) to reduce the chance of being blocked.

---

[Code and example in the online IDE](https://replit.com/@DimitryZub1/python-beautifulsoup-searching-google#main.py):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, lxml


with open("company_names.txt", mode="r") as in_file, \
     open("saved_company_names.txt", mode="w") as out_file:
    # read company names
    companies_list = [line.strip() for line in in_file.readlines()]

    for company_name in companies_list:
        # https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls
        params = {
            "q": f"{company_name} press release",
            "hl": "en",
            "gl": "us"
            }

        # https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#custom-headers
        headers = {
            "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/99.0.4758.87 Safari/537.36",
            }

        html = requests.get("https://www.google.com/search", params=params, headers=headers, timeout=30)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, "lxml")

        if "press" or "press-releases" or "press-release" or "PressReleases" or "pressreleases" in soup.select_one(".yuRUbf a")["href"]:
            out_file.write(f'{soup.select_one(".yuRUbf a")["href"]}\n')
```

Output from `saved_company_names.txt`:

```
http://www.pressreleasepoint.com/mojang
https://press.aboutamazon.com/press-releases
https://www.ebayinc.com/stories/press-room/
https://corporate.target.com/press
https://corporate.walmart.com/news/
https://ir.tesla.com/press
https://thewaltdisneycompany.com/press-releases/
https://about.netflix.com/en/newsroom
https://www.audi-mediacenter.com/en/press-releases
```

---

Alternatively, you can achieve the same thing using [Google Organic Results API](https://serpapi.com/organic-results) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free plan.

The difference is that it will handle blocks from Google or other search engines so the end-user need to think about what data to extract.

Example code to integrate:

```py
from serpapi import GoogleSearch
import os

with open("company_names.txt", mode="r") as in_file, \
     open("saved_company_names_serpapi.txt", mode="w") as out_file:
    # read company names
    companies_list = [line.strip() for line in in_file.readlines()]

    for company_name in companies_list:
        params = {
            "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY"),
            "engine": "google",
            "q": f"{company_name} press release",
            "gl": "us",
            "hl": "en"
            }

        search = GoogleSearch(params)
        results = search.get_dict()

        if "press" or "press-releases" or "press-release" or "PressReleases" or "pressreleases" in results["organic_results"][0]["link"]:
            out_file.write(f'{results["organic_results"][0]["link"]}\n')
```

Output from `saved_company_names_serpapi.txt`:

```
http://www.pressreleasepoint.com/mojang
https://press.aboutamazon.com/press-releases
https://www.ebayinc.com/stories/press-room/
https://corporate.target.com/press
https://corporate.walmart.com/news/
https://ir.tesla.com/press
https://thewaltdisneycompany.com/press-releases/
https://about.netflix.com/en/newsroom
https://www.audi-mediacenter.com/en/press-releases
```

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi